# i need to filter the epoc value based on start and end epoc value(which is in long) in hbase map reduce

Tags: hbase

I have written the custom comparator by extending `WritableByteArrayComparable` class for comparing the long value in hbase . Here is the code for reference.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.WritableByteArrayComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class LongWritableComparable extends WritableByteArrayComparable {

public LongWritableComparable() {
    super();
}

public LongWritableComparable(byte[] value) {
    super(value);
}

public LongWritableComparable(Long value) {
    super(Bytes.toBytes(value));
}


@Override
public int compareTo(byte[] otherValue, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    byte[] thisValue = this.getValue();
    long thisLong = Bytes.toLong(thisValue);
    long otherLong = Bytes.toLong(otherValue,arg1,arg2);

    if (thisLong == otherLong) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (thisLong < otherLong) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
  }

}
```

I used the comparator in the driver class like this:

```
long endtimelongval = Long.valueOf(datetime.get("endDate").getMillis()).longValue();

LongWritableComparable etval=new LongWritableComparable(endtimelongval);

SingleColumnValueFilter eventCreationEndTimeFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("d"), Bytes.toBytes("et"), CompareOp.LESS,etval );
```

When i execute the above code it throws following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter.<init>([B[BLorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/CompareFilter$CompareOp;Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/WritableByteArrayComparable;)V
```

in `SingleColumnValueFilter` line.

Anyone help me with your solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, no need to write a custom comparator. getMillis() will return in milli seconds, but in our hbase table we have the epoc value in seconds so i change to following and it works fine.
long startlongval=Long.valueOf(datetime.get("startDate").getMillis()).longValue()/1000l;
SingleColumnValueFilter eventCreationStartTimeFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("d"), Bytes.toBytes("et"), CompareOp.GREATER,Bytes.toBytes(startlongval));